# What causes Haxe error "Invalid build parameters"

Tags: compiler-errors, haxe

When I try to compile my project, Haxe gives a single line of output:

```
> haxe build.hxml
MyClass.hx:3: character 1 : Invalid build parameters
```

The line number points to a class in my code that looks fine...

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
```

What is the problem? Google has no hits for this error message.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

While the compiler error message confusingly points to the `MyClass.hx` file, the error is referring to the `@:autoBuild` specification ([docs](https://haxe.org/manual/macro-auto-build.html)), which is on the interface definition. There is likely a syntax error with this specification.

An example of correct syntax for this metadata is:

```
@:autoBuild( pkg.MyMacro.build_my_interface() )
interface MyInterface { }
```

This assumes that the `MyMacro` class is in the `pkg` package and has the specified build macro of this form:

```
public static macro function build_my_interface():Array<Field>
{
  var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
  // modify fields / etc
  return fields;
}
```

[Read more about build macros here](https://haxe.org/manual/macro-type-building.html).

### Possible Syntax Errors:

There are a few potential problems that may cause **Invalid build parameters**:

- The macro class is either not imported or not specified with the full package syntax.
- The build macro function is missing from the MyMacro class, or misspelled.
- You might have forgotten to call the build macro function (missing `()` at the end.)
- Note that the complete function call goes inside `@:autoBuild( )` (including optional function arguments) so check for mismatched parentheses.